# how to create class reference using String

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

so here's the problem that I'm facing.
Take a look

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ExpenseTableViewCell_Title") as! ExpenseTableViewCell_Title
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ExpenseTableViewCell_SaveCanel") as! ExpenseTableViewCell_SaveCanel
        return cell
    }
}
```

what i want to do is, use cell identifier string as cell type.(i.e. ExpenseTableViewCell_Title, ExpenseTableViewCell_SaveCanel).

I do have cell identifier array.

```
var TableCell:[ExpenseCellType] = [.ExpenseTableViewCell_Title, .ExpenseTableViewCell_SaveCanel]
```

Right now I only have two types of cell. But this number will go high.
And I don't want to use if/else condition or switch case.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Swift is strict with type checking. So you can't avoid this.

Answer (score 3):

Can make it shorter with extension:

```
extension UITableView {
    func dequeueReusable<T>(type: T.Type, index: IndexPath) -> T {
        return self.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: T.self), for: index) as! T
    }
}
```

Use it like this, will return `ExpenseTableViewCell_Title` type cell:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusable(type: ExpenseTableViewCell_Title.self, index: indexPath)
```

Just store your class in the array like `[ExpenseTableViewCell_Title.self, ExpenseTableViewCell_SaveCanel.self]` and pass it to this function

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use function `NSClassfromString`  but you will need namespace for getting class from String.

I have created example here to use it. 
Example:

```
func getClassFromString(_ className: String) -> AnyClass! {


    let namespace = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleExecutable"] as! String;
    let cls: AnyClass = NSClassFromString("\(namespace).\(className)")!;

    return cls;
}


    class customcell: UITableViewCell {

        }   

    let requiredclass = getClassFromString("customcell") as! UITableViewCell.Type
    let cellInstance = requiredclass.init()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I could find any function named "stringClassFromString". although I did tried "NSClassFromString". That didn't worked either.